# creating application to send message to specific subscriber on topic

Tags: spring-jms

I am creating a spring-jms integrated application with publisher/subscriber model, I am using ActiveMQ server. I want to make system such that message published by particular publisher should be received to the particular subscriber. I tried to accomplish it via  publish method of Topic Publisher but it hasn't worked. Please give some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a selector based filter. Configure the listener as below:

```
<jms:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactoryLpb"
        destination-type="dest" destination-resolver="destinationResolverBean">
        <jms:listener destination="ABC" ref="listenerBean"
            selector="string LIKE '%xyz%'" />
    </jms:listener-container>
```

Your publisher needs to add string property to the message indicating message content